# Connecting to ssl mysql always fails with error 2026

Tags: ssl, sql, mariadb, ssl-certificate-errors

I have mariadb version

> 10.1.21-MariaDB-1~jessie

(on debian 8) running a master-server replication scenario via ssl and it's working :

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show slave status\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: <MASTER_FQDN>
                  Master_User: replication_user
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 10
              Master_Log_File: sqlmaster-bin.000035
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 331
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 623
        Relay_Master_Log_File: sqlmaster-bin.000035
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 331
              Relay_Log_Space: 922
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: Yes
           Master_SSL_CA_File: /etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: /etc/mysql/ssl/
              Master_SSL_Cert: /etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: /etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: Yes
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
               Master_SSL_Crl: /etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: /etc/mysql/ssl/
                   Using_Gtid: Current_Pos
                  Gtid_IO_Pos: 0-1-440
      Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids: 
                Parallel_Mode: conservative
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The problem is, no matter what client I try to connect with to the server (workbench, navicat, heidisql, other mysql instances, other mysql.exe windows instances etc) I get this error:

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unknown error number
```

I really don't know how to fix this, I've been working on it for 8hrs+ :) Please assist.